# All the ports are not working of my Raspberry Pi 3 (4 USB port and ethernet port)

Tags: pi-3, usb, ethernet, led

According to my knowledge, in my circuit only power light of Raspberry Pi is working but all other component such as USB port and Ethernet port is not working. Please help me......

I have just bought my new Raspberry Pi circuit, but after installing my OS in SD card when I try to connect my Raspberry Pi with laptop (using Ethernet cable); my Ethernet port on laptop side(and also circuit side) do not blinking. To check USB port connectivity, I used my USB hub which have red LED which blinking when power is on, but this USB hub is also not blinking when connected to the Raspberry Pi 3 circuit.

Comment: Start with [R-Pi Troubleshooting](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting), and if still not working, come back and update your post with additional information.

Comment: BTW, if the red LED on your Raspberry Pi blinking, it means that you have a weaker power supply (need 5V, 1A at least). Also, are you saying you connect your Raspberry Pi directly to your laptop with ethernet? Please update your post and provide more info (e.g. how do you connect your keyboard and display? etc.)